# обработка результатов запроса hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Начинаю изучать java. Подскажите, т.к. уже облазил кучу статей, а решения так и не нашел. Ощущение, что начинаю все больше и больше запутываться.

Есть следующий класс:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CalendarResPlan")
public class CalendarResPlanSet implements Serializable { 

     @Id
     @Column(name = "id")
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Long id;

     @Column(name = "day")
     @Temporal(value=TemporalType.DATE)
     private Date day;

     @Column(name = "idRes")
     private String idRes;

     @Column(name = "needTime")
     private Long needTime;

     @Column(name = "idOperation")
     private String idOperation;
```

Делаю выборку следующим образом:

```
        Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT "
                                        + "SUM(R.needTime), "
                                        + "R.day, "
                                        + "R.idRes "
                                        + "FROM "
                                        + "CalendarResPlanSet R "
                                        + "WHERE R.day = :day "
                                        + "AND R.idRes = :idRes "
                                        + "GROUP BY "
                                        + "R.day, "
                                        + "R.idRes");
        query.setParameter("day", day);
        query.setParameter("idRes", idRes);

CalendarResPlanSet planSet = (CalendarResPlanSet) query.uniqueResult();
```

Преобразование не получается. Выдает следующее сообщение:
cannot be cast to base.dataSets.CalendarResPlanSet

Comment: Я хоть и не спец по Hibernate, но нельзя же делать группировку по таблице с подсчетом суммы и пытаться прикинуться обычной записью из таблицы. Вот оно и не кастится, как я понимаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать агрегатные функции в HQL/JPQL, то у вас есть два варианта получения результатов:

1. Получения списка массивов объектов - `List<Object[]>`. Элемент списка - это строка, элемент массива - поле в строке:

   ```
   Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT "
                                   + "SUM(R.needTime), "
                                   + "R.day, "
                                   + "R.idRes "
                                   + "FROM "
                                   + "CalendarResPlanSet R "
                                   + "WHERE R.day = :day "
                                   + "AND R.idRes = :idRes "
                                   + "GROUP BY "
                                   + "R.day, "
                                   + "R.idRes");
   query.setParameter("day", day);
   query.setParameter("idRes", idRes);

   List<Object[]> data = query.list();
   if (data.size() > 0) {
       Long needTimeSum = data.get(0)[0];
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Создание объектов в запросе:

   ```
   @Entity
   public class CalendarResPlanSet {
       ...
       public CalendarResPlanSet(Date day, String idRes, Long needTime) {
           this.day = day;
           this.idRes = idRes;
           this.needTime = needTime;
       }
       ...
   }

   Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT "
                           + "new CalendarResPlanSet("
                           + "R.day, "
                           + "R.idRes, "
                           + "SUM(R.needTime)"
                           + ") "
                           + "FROM "
                           + "CalendarResPlanSet R "
                           + "WHERE R.day = :day "
                           + "AND R.idRes = :idRes "
                           + "GROUP BY "
                           + "R.day, "
                           + "R.idRes");
   query.setParameter("day", day);
   query.setParameter("idRes", idRes);

   CalendarResPlanSet calResPlanSet = (CalendarResPlanSet) query.uniqueResult();
   ```

   Только учтите, что полученная сущность будет в состоянии transient и инициализирована не полностью.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)